# Javascript/jQuery Use a variable as a index

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
 function changeContactPersonDetails(value){
    value = value-1;
    alert(typeof(value))  // alerts number
    $("#billingPersonName").val("${session.traineeDetais.name[value]}");

}
```

Here  i want to use value as a index (i.e 0,1,2,3 etc)

but gives me error, if i try something like this

```
  $("#billingPersonName").val("${session.traineeDetais.name[1]}");
```

gives correct value

Comment: Try :  `$("#billingPersonName").val("${session.traineeDetais.name["+value+"]}");`

Comment: its concatenation problem

Answer (score 7):

here `value` is a variable so you need to use string concatenation

```
$("#billingPersonName").val("${session.traineeDetais.name[" + value + "]}");
```

Answer (score 2):

Change function to:

```
function changeContactPersonDetails(value){
    value = value-1;
    alert(typeof(value))  // alerts number
    $("#billingPersonName").val("${session.traineeDetais.name["+value+"]}");

}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$("#billingPersonName").val("${session.traineeDetais.name[" + parseInt(value,10) + "]}");
```